# Vue.js cannot read property of null/undefined of nested object in Props

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

So i get an object from an axios call. I pass the object to a child element. Then in that child element i loop through the object to read a property of another nested object. and here i get the warning that the property i'm trying to read undefined/null. i did check the console and i'm receiving everthing properly the problem is in reading that nested property.
The Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of null
```

The object i receive looks like the following

```
{
    "images": [
        "1616575030315IMG-20210211-WA0003.jpg",
        "1616575030316IMG-20210211-WA0004.jpg",
        "1616575030316IMG-20210211-WA0000.jpg"
    ],
    "_id": "605afa36320a772cecc4ed85",
    "name": "Maman",
    "brand": "Zara",
    "user": {
        "email": [
            "zakisb97@gmail.com"
        ],
        "_id": "6061bd38ada425383cc8a5b2",
        "username": "zakisb97",
        "tel": "0560728063",
        "apropos": "salam123456",
    },
    "type": "Robes",
    "size": "M",
    "description": "Good to wear",
    "price": "150",
}
```

Parent component: Market Products

```
    <div
        v-for="product in products"
        class=""
        :key="product.id"
    >
        <product-default :product="product"  />
    </div>
```

The product default child component

```
<h1>{{ product.user.username }}</h1> // results in undefined

export default {
    props: {
        product: {
            type: Object,
            require: true,
            default: () => {}
        },
    },
   data: () => ({
       // nothing here
    }),
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably accessing object property while the object is `undefined`.
Try this:

```
    <div
        v-for="product in products"
        class=""
        :key="product.id"
    >
        <product-default v-if="product" :product="product"  />
    </div>
```

and this:

```
<h1 v-if="product && product.user">{{ product.user.username }}</h1>
```

Comment: Same problem. i did check the data i get. All products are defined have the username property.

Comment: Are you sure that all of the products have `user` property defined? What if you add this to `h1`: `v-if="product && product.user"`

Comment: you were right i just rechecked the problem resulted in having user that didn't exist. because while developing i did remove their record from the DB . Thanks a lot of man !